# If the time is 00:00 or past midnight need to add 1 day?

Tags: c#, datetime, time

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(d["working_date"].ToString());
TimeSpan tm = TimeSpan.Parse(d["despatch_dt_tm"].ToString());
TimeSpan tm3 = TimeSpan.Parse("23:59:59");
TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);

if ((tm > tm3 && tm < end))
{
    dt.Date.AddDays(1);
}
```

I need to to checking if tm is past midnight than need to add 1 day.
I tried using datetime and timespan not working.
Is there any other way to do this kind of checking?

Comment: What time isn't "past midnight"?

Comment: tm is a timespan which represents time duration, not date time.

Comment: Perhaps you should read [ask]?

Answer (score 0):

Thats how I'll solve your problem:

Remember `last tm` in first iteration.

If `current tm` is smaller than `last tm`:

- than add 1 day
- else write current tm as last

Example of code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(d["working_date"].ToString());
TimeSpan tm = TimeSpan.Parse(d["despatch_dt_tm"].ToString());

if (tm < lastTm )
{
dt.Date.AddDays(1);
}
else
{
lastTm=tm;
}
```

Comment: so the lastTm i set to 00:00 ?

Comment: @hunt, yes, you could set it to 00:00.